# Juju - Wordpress hook failed : install

Tags: juju, maas

I am using ubuntu server 14.04 LTS, have 3 nodes to deploy wordpress, mysql and juju-gui. After I deployed wordpress, it went pxe boot to install the OS and then I got this error, but first of all im going to share the setup I did.

sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install juju

juju generate-config - did my conf **for MaaS environment**

And because sometimes after bootstrap I get restricted or don't get internet access, I downloaded the juju tools - wget - c https://streams.canonical.com/juju/tools/releases/juju-1.20.11-trusty-amd64.tgz
and added to juju environment conf file

tools-metadata-url: http://172.16.1.160/juju-metadata/tools

juju bootstrap

sudo apt-get install bzr

mkdir –p /opt/charms/trusty; cd /opt/charms/trusty

bzr branch lp:charms/wordpress

juju deploy –-repository=/opt/charms local:trusty/wordpress

and then the error, after the pxe boot:

[image]

[image]

How do I solve this issue? Thanks in advance!

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you run `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:charmers/charm-helpers` and add the output to your question?

Comment: Added 3 printscreens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect your MAAS node cannot reach out to the internet to install the necessary software. The charm-helpers PPA is being used by the node, not your local machine.

Comment: Yes, even if I do: juju deploy wordpress, it gives a error saying he can't access the charm store.

Comment: If you are behind a proxy, this might help: http://askubuntu.com/questions/430865/juju-http-proxy-and-no-proxy-settings