# Juju - Can't access juju charm store

Tags: juju, maas

I am using ubuntu 14.04, and 1 node only. I did

juju deploy --to 0 –-repository=/opt/charms local:trusty/wordpress

[image]

Did debug and got this:

[image]

I think this is a proxy issue, but I have no proxy, so I am trying to do this command but seems like I am doing it wrong.

[image]

Help me with this issue. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proxy settings for juju are explained in this question/answer:

[juju http-proxy and no_proxy settings](https://askubuntu.com/questions/430865/juju-http-proxy-and-no-proxy-settings)